# Constructible numbers defined over the rationals

Tags: geometry, field-theory

> If $z$ is constructible, then its minimal irreducible polynomial has a degree a power of $2$. Does the polynomial have to be defined over the rationals?

I am asking this because we can equivalently define a constructible number if the field extension $\mathbf{Q}(z)/\mathbf{Q}$ has dimension a power of $2$. Why do we define it over the rationals like that? Can we define it over the reals?

Comment: What do you mean by "have to be defined over the rationals"?

Comment: @Wojowu I mean a polynomial defined over $\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: I still don't think I understand. What do you mean by "defined over $\Bbb Q$"? Do you mean it has to have rational coefficients?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: There are algebraic numbers whose degree is a power of $2$, but that are non constructible : $z$ constructible $\implies$ $[Q(z):Q]=2^n$, but $[Q(z):Q]=2^n$ $\nRightarrow z$ constructible.

Comment: If you talk about minimal polynomial of a number, you have to specify over which field it's a minimal polynomial, otherwise it's implicitly taken to be $\Bbb Q$. A minimal polynomial over a field $F$ has to have coefficients in $F$. By the way, the first sentence after the question (the "I am asking this...") is wrong. It should be that the degree of splitting field of the minimal polynomial has degree power of 2.

Comment: @Watson You are right. I made a typo it should say $a$ power of $2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number $a$ is called constructible here if there exists a classic geometric construction (that is: using straightedge and compasses [and for the sake of completeness: picking a generic point]) that can construct a line segment of length $a$ times as long as a single given line segment. Since addition, subtraction, multiplication (regarding the given length as unit length) and division are possible with the tools allowed, we se ethat the set of constructible numbers is a field $F$, more precisely a field extension of $\Bbb Q$. Given that only countably many constructions exist, the field must also be countable, hence it certainly does not contain all of $\Bbb R$.

Apart from the field operations as mentioned, we can use the classic tools to find solutions to quadratics, i.e., if lengths $p,q$ are given, we can explicitly construct $x$ such that $x^2+px+q=0$. And on the other hand, any point constructed as intersection of lines and/or circles can be seen to be the solution of a quadratic equation with some given data (points, distances, slopes, radii) as coefficients. 
We conclude that - if we let $F_n$ be the smallest extension field of $\Bbb Q$  containing all available numbers after $n$ construction steps - the field $F_{n+1}$ is the same as or of degree $2$ over $F_n$. By induction, $F_n$ is of degree at most $2^n$ over $\Bbb Q$. As a consequence, every constructable number, which must be in an $F_n$ for some $n$, is of degree a power of $2$ over the rationals.
Note that we actually have slightly more because there exists a tower of field extensions where each step is one of degree $2$.

---

Instead of (geometrically) constructable numbers *per se*, we *could* speek of number constructible over an extension field $F$ over $\Bbb Q$. That would be numbers that can be constructed with the classic tools *provided* we are given enough points to have $F$ "available" to start with. For example if $F$ is finitely generated over $\Bbb Q$ such as $F=\Bbb Q[\sqrt 3]$ or $F=\Bbb Q(\pi)$, we should be given line segments of length $1$ as well as some of length ts of the generators (that is, porsimplicty identify the plane with $\Bbb C$ ans assume $0$, $1$, and $\sqrt 3$ (or $\pi$) are given.

Comment: Take for example $\sqrt[3]{2}$. It's minimal polynomial has degree $3$ over $\mathbf{Q}$. The fact that it is defined over $\mathbf{Q}$ doesn't matter?